# What is suspicious about this phrase " American famous Doctor of Neurology"?

Tags: adjectives

What is suspicious about this phrase " American famous Doctor of Neurology" circulating on social media?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by suspicious, nor why you say it is circulating on social media.  Google says "No results found for "American famous Doctor of Neurology"."

Comment: @James K: You shouldn't rely on a single source: "Google says".  There's also duckduckgo.com
 https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/mayim-bialik-cbd-allegations/

Comment: Well this is exactly the point.  It is your job, @Tim, to tell me where you read this phrase.  It's not my job to search multiple search engines in the hope of finding what bit of social media you've been reading. Google doesn't find every article on Snopes on the day it is published.  So you have to tell us "I read this on Snopes".

Comment: You still need to explain what you mean by "suspicious".  Also the Snopes article is dated March 14th,  so cannot have been the source of your question, so you also haven't explained where you read this phrase.

Comment: @James K.  No, it was not my source; rather it was looking at the items circulating on the internet that I referred to in my question! Just because you could not find them when you used Google did not license you to state "I don't know ... why you say it is circulating".  Do you understand that point?  It's not my responsibility to tell you how to find things on the internet. If you need help doing that, ask.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by *suspicious*, but it might be that the word order sounds wrong to native English speakers.  The natural word order would be "**famous American** doctor".

The [order of adjectives in English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order) is

1. opinion
2. size
3. physical quality
4. shape
5. age
6. color
7. origin
8. material
9. type
10. purpose

*American* is origin, and *famous* is opinion, so *famous* should come first.  If you get the order wrong, you sound like somebody who does not speak English fluently.  No famous American doctor would describe himself or herself as an "American famous doctor"!

Comment: I always find it odd/amazing that a native will usually have absorbed this totally unconsciously & probably couldn't set them out in order even if asked. Nonetheless, they can usually trot them out in at least a close approximation of the correct order without even thinking about it.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. And perhaps this would be a good place to point out that the rules are not always so strict. (For example, "ugly" usually goes after "big" but before "little".)

Comment: @gonefishin'again. - one can absorb rules and conventions unconsciously. Native speakers do this in infancy. One encounters them in heard speech or written material. I don;t know how many times you have to hear or read 'famous French chef', 'delicious German sausage', 'old Japanese proverb' before you know the 'right' way to say such things. It's how language works.